# javascript discord case insensitive error

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm new at JavaScript. I'm making a discord bot but I always get error saying that `message.startsWith is not a function` the reason is I wan't to make the bot chat respond to be not case insensitive. I'm on discord.js version 12.2.0 and
this is my code:

````js
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    msg = message.content.toLowerCase();
    if (message.startsWith(prefix + "laugh")) {
      message.author.send ("```haha lmao```")
    }
}
````

I've been searching my problem on the internet but none of them solve my problem. It's been 3 days since I got this error.

Comment: What if replace `message.startsWith(prefix + "laugh")` with `msg.startsWith(prefix + "laugh")`?

Comment: You forgot do declarate `msg` (`const msg = [...]`).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `startsWith` is not supported. Check if `String.prototype.startsWith` is true.

Also you can use `indexOf` instead.

````
if (message.indexOf(prefix + "laugh") === 0) {
    message.author.send ("```haha lmao```")
}
````

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace `message` to `message.content` if you want to retrieve the full message sent by the user.

The message constructor contains much more than the user's message, see [the docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message).